# Difference between " among" and "of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the difference between " among" and "of" in the given context?

> 1: I like botany **among** all the subjects.
>   2: I like botany **of** all the subjects.

Can I use both interchangeably or they mean different?

Answer (score 1):

**Among**, **of**, and **out of** are all essentially interchangeable in this context. However, it sounds a little unusual to mention the other subjects, since they are irrelevant to you liking botany. It sounds more natural to actually draw the comparison:

> I like botany.
>
> Among all the subjects, I **prefer** botany.
>
> Of all the subjects, I **favor** botany.
>
> I like botany **the best** (or **the most**) out of all the subjects.